# Animate the opening of MainPage from App.xaml.cs in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When pushing a page in Xamarin Forms I can animate it easily by setting the animate property to true

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(NavigationPageHelper.Create(new MyPage(), true);
```

How can I achieve the same thing when opening the MainPage from App.xaml.cs, in the App() constructor?  I see MainPage as a .Animate extension but I've not found any decent examples of how to use it.

```
InitializeComponent();
MainPage = GetMainPage(); // GetMainPage returns the correct page to open
MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarTextColorProperty, Color.White);
```

UPDATE

I found this code to place in the override of OnAppearing, I can see what it *should* be doing but it doesn't actually do anything,  Can anyone see why?

```
this.Animate("", (s) => Layout(new Rectangle(X, (1 - s) * Height, Width, Height)), 0, 600, Easing.SpringIn, null, null);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must set a timeout for the animation to take effect. `OnAppearing` is called a lot of time before the `Page` actually appears. Insert your animation in a timeout, like this..

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => BounceUp());
```

Being `BounceUp` your animation story board.

Update: You must also use the modifier `async` in `OnAppearing` method

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer, it does as you say but it also seems to initially show the page, then for the Task.Delay it shows the splash again, then after the delay it does the bounce, I'll just have to work out how to go from splash to bounce seemlessly

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, seems like whenever I use the task.delay before showing any page with the animation, the splash is visible for the delay, appreciate the suggestion but there's something else going in here that I need to figure out

Comment: Greggz, You should add those relevant information in your answer. =). @DarkW1nter the problem with the `splash` was relevant to your question, I guess it must be on its body as well. This talk so will be able to be deleted.

Comment: Sorry guys, wasn't here. I updated it already to use the `async` modifier

Comment: Hi Greggz, app is taken lot of time when page is appearing , at a time you have asked to use this Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => BounceUp());                           But when again open the page, its not taken the more time for page loading, since it has been taken lot of time only when page is appearing on first time. In this case, no need to use Task.Delay function.                                                             How to acheive this? how to find the page is appeared or not?

Comment: @sameer Have you checked this event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.appearing?view=xamarin-forms